# Error When Adding Invoice

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am using IPP's PHP API to create invoices. I am creating the invoice using the following code:

```
public function create_invoice($data) {

    $this->_getClientByID($data['clientId']);
    $invoice = new IPPInvoice();

    $invoice->AllowIPNPayment = "false";
    $invoice->AllowOnlinePayment = "false";
    $invoice->AllowOnlineCreditCardPayment = "false";
    $invoice->AllowOnlineACHPayment = "false";
    $invoice->ApplyTaxAfterDiscount = "false";
    $invoice->CustomerRef = $data['clientId'];
    $invoice->BillAddr = $this->_client[0]->BillAddr;
    $invoice->ShipAddr = $this->_client[0]->ShipAddr;
    $invoice->DueDate = Date('Y-m-d');
    $invoice->PrintStatus = "NotSet";
    $invoice->EmailStatus = "EmailSent";
    $invoice->BillEmail = array('id'=>'', 'address'=>$data['email'],'default'=>'','tag'=>'');
    $invoice->TxnDate = Date('Y-m-d');
    $invoice->CurrencyRef = "USD";

    $lineItems = array();

    $invoiceTotal = 0;

    foreach ($data['invoice_items'] as $line) {
        $lineItem = new IPPLine();
        $invoiceTotal = $invoiceTotal + $line->amount;
        $lineItem->Description = $line->service_name;
        $lineItem->Amount = $line->amount;

        $salesLineItem = new IPPSalesItemLineDetail();
        $salesLineItem->ItemRef = 1;
        $salesLineItem->UnitPrice = $line->amount;
        $salesLineItem->Qty = 1;

        $lineItem->DetailType = "SalesItemLineDetail";
        $lineItem->SalesItemLineDetail = $salesLineItem;

        $lineItems[] = $lineItem;
    }

    $lineItem = new IPPLine();
    $lineItem->DetailType = "SubTotalLineDetail";
    $lineItem->Amount = $invoiceTotal;

    $lineItems[] = $lineItem;

    $invoice->Line = $lineItems;
    $invoice->TotalAmt = $invoiceTotal;
    $invoice->Balance = $invoiceTotal;


    $result = $this->_dataService->Add($invoice);

}
```

Which, for my example produces the following data:

```
{  
   Deposit:"",
   AllowIPNPayment:"false",
   AllowOnlinePayment:"false",
   AllowOnlineCreditCardPayment:"false",
   AllowOnlineACHPayment:"false",
   EInvoiceStatus:"",
   ECloudStatusTimeStamp:"",
   InvoiceEx:"",
   AutoDocNumber:"",
   CustomerRef:"889",
   CustomerMemo:"",
   BillAddr:{  
      Id:"5438",
      Line1:"2021E Pulasky Highway",
      Line2:"",
      Line3:"",
      Line4:"",
      Line5:"",
      City:"Havre de Grace",
      Country:"US",
      CountryCode:"",
      CountrySubDivisionCode:"MD",
      PostalCode:"21078",
      PostalCodeSuffix:"",
      Lat:"",
      Long:"",
      Tag:"",
      Note:""
   },
   ShipAddr:{  
      Id:"5438",
      Line1:"2021E Pulasky Highway",
      Line2:"",
      Line3:"",
      Line4:"",
      Line5:"",
      City:"Havre de Grace",
      Country:"US",
      CountryCode:"",
      CountrySubDivisionCode:"MD",
      PostalCode:"21078",
      PostalCodeSuffix:"",
      Lat:"",
      Long:"",
      Tag:"",
      Note:""
   },
   RemitToRef:"",
   ClassRef:"",
   SalesTermRef:"",
   DueDate:"2014-08-28",
   SalesRepRef:"",
   PONumber:"",
   FOB:"",
   ShipMethodRef:"",
   ShipDate:"",
   TrackingNum:"",
   GlobalTaxCalculation:"",
   TotalAmt:"44.85",
   HomeTotalAmt:"",
   ApplyTaxAfterDiscount:"false",
   TemplateRef:"",
   PrintStatus:"NotSet",
   EmailStatus:"EmailSent",
   BillEmail:{  
      id:"",
      address:"",
      default:"",
      tag:""
   },
   ARAccountRef:"",
   Balance:"44.85",
   FinanceCharge:"",
   PaymentMethodRef:"",
   PaymentRefNum:"",
   PaymentType:"",
   CheckPayment:"",
   CreditCardPayment:"",
   DepositToAccountRef:"",
   DeliveryInfo:"",
   DocNumber:"",
   TxnDate:"2014-08-28",
   DepartmentRef:"",
   CurrencyRef:"USD",
   ExchangeRate:"",
   PrivateNote:"",
   TxnStatus:"",
   LinkedTxn:"",
   Line:{  
      0:{  
         Id:"",
         LineNum:"",
         Description:"Hosting - Standard",
         Amount:"14.95",
         LinkedTxn:"",
         DetailType:"SalesItemLineDetail",
         PaymentLineDetail:"",
         DiscountLineDetail:"",
         TaxLineDetail:"",
         SalesItemLineDetail:{  
            ServiceDate:"",
            TaxInclusiveAmt:"",
            SalesItemLineDetailEx:"",
            ItemRef:"1",
            ClassRef:"",
            UnitPrice:"14.95",
            RatePercent:"",
            PriceLevelRef:"",
            MarkupInfo:"",
            Qty:"1",
            UOMRef:"",
            ItemAccountRef:"",
            InventorySiteRef:"",
            TaxCodeRef:""
         },
         DescriptionLineDetail:"",
         ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail:"",
         AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail:"",
         DepositLineDetail:"",
         PurchaseOrderItemLineDetail:"",
         SalesOrderItemLineDetail:"",
         ItemReceiptLineDetail:"",
         JournalEntryLineDetail:"",
         GroupLineDetail:"",
         SubTotalLineDetail:"",
         CustomField:"",
         LineEx:""
      },
      1:{  
         Id:"",
         LineNum:"",
         Description:"Hosting - Standard",
         Amount:"14.95",
         LinkedTxn:"",
         DetailType:"SalesItemLineDetail",
         PaymentLineDetail:"",
         DiscountLineDetail:"",
         TaxLineDetail:"",
         SalesItemLineDetail:{  
            ServiceDate:"",
            TaxInclusiveAmt:"",
            SalesItemLineDetailEx:"",
            ItemRef:"1",
            ClassRef:"",
            UnitPrice:"14.95",
            RatePercent:"",
            PriceLevelRef:"",
            MarkupInfo:"",
            Qty:"1",
            UOMRef:"",
            ItemAccountRef:"",
            InventorySiteRef:"",
            TaxCodeRef:""
         },
         DescriptionLineDetail:"",
         ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail:"",
         AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail:"",
         DepositLineDetail:"",
         PurchaseOrderItemLineDetail:"",
         SalesOrderItemLineDetail:"",
         ItemReceiptLineDetail:"",
         JournalEntryLineDetail:"",
         GroupLineDetail:"",
         SubTotalLineDetail:"",
         CustomField:"",
         LineEx:""
      },
      2:{  
         Id:"",
         LineNum:"",
         Description:"Hosting - Standard",
         Amount:"14.95",
         LinkedTxn:"",
         DetailType:"SalesItemLineDetail",
         PaymentLineDetail:"",
         DiscountLineDetail:"",
         TaxLineDetail:"",
         SalesItemLineDetail:{  
            ServiceDate:"",
            TaxInclusiveAmt:"",
            SalesItemLineDetailEx:"",
            ItemRef:"1",
            ClassRef:"",
            UnitPrice:"14.95",
            RatePercent:"",
            PriceLevelRef:"",
            MarkupInfo:"",
            Qty:"1",
            UOMRef:"",
            ItemAccountRef:"",
            InventorySiteRef:"",
            TaxCodeRef:""
         },
         DescriptionLineDetail:"",
         ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail:"",
         AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail:"",
         DepositLineDetail:"",
         PurchaseOrderItemLineDetail:"",
         SalesOrderItemLineDetail:"",
         ItemReceiptLineDetail:"",
         JournalEntryLineDetail:"",
         GroupLineDetail:"",
         SubTotalLineDetail:"",
         CustomField:"",
         LineEx:""
      },
      3:{  
         Id:"",
         LineNum:"",
         Description:"",
         Amount:"44.85",
         LinkedTxn:"",
         DetailType:"SubTotalLineDetail",
         PaymentLineDetail:"",
         DiscountLineDetail:"",
         TaxLineDetail:"",
         SalesItemLineDetail:"",
         DescriptionLineDetail:"",
         ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail:"",
         AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail:"",
         DepositLineDetail:"",
         PurchaseOrderItemLineDetail:"",
         SalesOrderItemLineDetail:"",
         ItemReceiptLineDetail:"",
         JournalEntryLineDetail:"",
         GroupLineDetail:"",
         SubTotalLineDetail:"",
         CustomField:"",
         LineEx:""
      }
   },
   TxnTaxDetail:"",
   TxnSource:"",
   Id:"",
   SyncToken:"",
   MetaData:"",
   CustomField:"",
   AttachableRef:"",
   domain:"",
   status:"",
   sparse:""
}
```

However, when my code runs, it fails on the `$result = $this->_dataService->Add($invoice);` line, and produces the following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught IdsException: [0]: 2014-08-28 13:24:33 - /var/www/emoxie.com/vendor/emoxie/quickbooks-sdk/src/DataService/DataService.php - 335 - CheckNullResponseAndThrowException - Response Null or Empty thrown in /var/www/emoxie.com/vendor/emoxie/quickbooks-sdk/src/Core/CoreHelper.php on line 95
```

DataService.php Line 335
    CoreHelper::CheckNullResponseAndThrowException($responseBody);

Has anyone ever come across this and have a fix?

Comment: does ````echo $data['clientId'];```` return anything?

Comment: I assume you're trying to interact with Quickbook online. Can you please share the code snippets where you are creating the DataServices object ( using context object). Please make sure you are using correct service type ( i.e QBO ) unless your apptoken works with both (QBO and QBD). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of an Invoice for a US based company. Please match your invoice against this.-

```
<Invoice xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
  <DocNumber>96</DocNumber>
  <TxnDate>2014-08-21</TxnDate>
  <CurrencyRef name="Angolan Kwanza">AOA</CurrencyRef>
  <ExchangeRate>1</ExchangeRate>
  <Line>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <LineNum>1</LineNum>
    <Amount>23.00</Amount>
    <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
    <SalesItemLineDetail>
      <ItemRef name="bat">3</ItemRef>
      <UnitPrice>23</UnitPrice>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <TaxCodeRef>10</TaxCodeRef>
    </SalesItemLineDetail>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Amount>23.00</Amount>
    <DetailType>SubTotalLineDetail</DetailType>
    <SubTotalLineDetail />
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Amount>0.46</Amount>
    <DetailType>DiscountLineDetail</DetailType>
    <DiscountLineDetail>
      <PercentBased>true</PercentBased>
      <DiscountPercent>2</DiscountPercent>
      <DiscountAccountRef name="Discounts given">74</DiscountAccountRef>
    </DiscountLineDetail>
  </Line>
  <TxnTaxDetail>
    <TotalTax>2.25</TotalTax>
    <TaxLine>
      <Amount>2.25</Amount>
      <DetailType>TaxLineDetail</DetailType>
      <TaxLineDetail>
        <TaxRateRef>20</TaxRateRef>
        <PercentBased>true</PercentBased>
        <TaxPercent>10</TaxPercent>
        <NetAmountTaxable>22.54</NetAmountTaxable>
      </TaxLineDetail>
    </TaxLine>
  </TxnTaxDetail>
  <CustomerRef name="gg">3</CustomerRef>
  <SalesTermRef>3</SalesTermRef>
  <DueDate>2014-09-20</DueDate>
  <GlobalTaxCalculation>TaxExcluded</GlobalTaxCalculation>
  <TotalAmt>24.79</TotalAmt>
  <HomeTotalAmt>24.79</HomeTotalAmt>
  <PrintStatus>NotSet</PrintStatus>
  <EmailStatus>NotSet</EmailStatus>
  <BillEmail>
    <Address>foop@gmail.com</Address>
  </BillEmail>
  <Balance>24.79</Balance>
  <Deposit>0</Deposit>
  <AllowIPNPayment>false</AllowIPNPayment>
  <AllowOnlinePayment>false</AllowOnlinePayment>
  <AllowOnlineCreditCardPayment>false</AllowOnlineCreditCardPayment>
  <AllowOnlineACHPayment>false</AllowOnlineACHPayment>
</Invoice>



<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-08-20T23:23:07.692-07:00">
  <Invoice domain="QBO" sparse="false">
<Id>14</Id>
<SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
<MetaData>
  <CreateTime>2014-08-20T23:23:07-07:00</CreateTime>
  <LastUpdatedTime>2014-08-20T23:23:07-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
</MetaData>
<DocNumber>96</DocNumber>
<TxnDate>2014-08-21</TxnDate>
<CurrencyRef name="Angolan Kwanza">AOA</CurrencyRef>
<ExchangeRate>1</ExchangeRate>
<Line>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <LineNum>1</LineNum>
  <Amount>23.00</Amount>
  <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
  <SalesItemLineDetail>
    <ItemRef name="bat">3</ItemRef>
    <UnitPrice>23</UnitPrice>
    <Qty>1</Qty>
    <TaxCodeRef>10</TaxCodeRef>
  </SalesItemLineDetail>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Amount>23.00</Amount>
  <DetailType>SubTotalLineDetail</DetailType>
  <SubTotalLineDetail />
</Line>
<Line>
  <Amount>0.46</Amount>
  <DetailType>DiscountLineDetail</DetailType>
  <DiscountLineDetail>
    <PercentBased>true</PercentBased>
    <DiscountPercent>2</DiscountPercent>
    <DiscountAccountRef name="Discounts given">74</DiscountAccountRef>
  </DiscountLineDetail>
</Line>
<TxnTaxDetail>
  <TotalTax>2.25</TotalTax>
  <TaxLine>
    <Amount>2.25</Amount>
    <DetailType>TaxLineDetail</DetailType>
    <TaxLineDetail>
      <TaxRateRef>20</TaxRateRef>
      <PercentBased>true</PercentBased>
      <TaxPercent>10</TaxPercent>
      <NetAmountTaxable>22.54</NetAmountTaxable>
    </TaxLineDetail>
  </TaxLine>
</TxnTaxDetail>
<CustomerRef name="gg">3</CustomerRef>
<SalesTermRef>3</SalesTermRef>
<DueDate>2014-09-20</DueDate>
<GlobalTaxCalculation>TaxExcluded</GlobalTaxCalculation>
<TotalAmt>24.79</TotalAmt>
<HomeTotalAmt>24.79</HomeTotalAmt>
<PrintStatus>NotSet</PrintStatus>
<EmailStatus>NotSet</EmailStatus>
<BillEmail>
  <Address>foop@gmail.com</Address>
</BillEmail>
<Balance>24.79</Balance>
<Deposit>0</Deposit>
<AllowIPNPayment>false</AllowIPNPayment>
<AllowOnlinePayment>false</AllowOnlinePayment>
<AllowOnlineCreditCardPayment>false</AllowOnlineCreditCardPayment>
<AllowOnlineACHPayment>false</AllowOnlineACHPayment>
```

You need to send SalesItemLineDetail also in your line. Please refer these docs for sample invoice and basic tags that need to be sent.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/invoice

Refer this for understanding all data types and key concepts-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/0700_other_topics
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services

Alternatively create an Invoice in UI and then read it using API explorer. Compare with your xml request. You will get an idea of how the correct payload should be.

Comment: Edited my original question with new details per your answer.

Comment: Don't know if this helps but check the JSON example here- See that your ref tags like CustomerRef or ItmeRef has direct Id assigned but in the sample create json here-https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/invoice , the CustomerRef has Value with the Id.

Comment: Do the same for all ref tags.